# jQuery .post not working only in Firefox Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreatePost(){
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery.post( "../../setPercentPayment.php", function( data ) {
        });
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

This code is working fire with Opera, Google Chrome and even in IE.
But there is a problem with the .post function it seems in the Firefox.

How i can make this .post function works in Firefox also ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sent data as AJAX just to reload the complete document, interesting. And what do you sent to payment - in your example, nothing. It is: jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] ) - what does your function do?

Comment: What happens if you don't call the `location.reload()`? Does Firefox then send the POST request? If you really need to reload then put that call in the success handler of the POST.